# Not able to configure hadoop

Tags: hadoop, java-home

I am not able to configure hadoop for stand alone operation.
When i am doing cp conf/*.xml input, i am getting these errors:
cp: cannot create regular file `input/capacity-scheduler.xml': Permission denied
cp: cannot create regular file`input/core-site.xml': Permission denied
cp: cannot create regular file `input/fair-scheduler.xml': Permission denied
cp: cannot create regular file`input/hadoop-policy.xml': Permission denied
cp: cannot create regular file `input/hdfs-site.xml': Permission denied
cp: cannot create regular file`input/mapred-queue-acls.xml': Permission denied
cp: cannot create regular file `input/mapred-site.xml': Permission denied

And after that when i am doing bin/hadoop jar hadoop-examples-*.jar grep input output 'dfs[a-z.]+',i am getting these errors:

/cygdrive/d/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../conf/hadoop-env.sh: line 55: $'\r': command                                                                                                     not found
Error: JAVA_HOME is not set.
I have edited the env.sh file and have set the JAVA_HOME.

Can anyone suggest me something?

Comment: Waiting for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try running those copy commands as the root user (administrator). It's probably a permissions issue where your user account doesn't have the privileges to write things in that directory.

You can do this in a lot of Linux distributions by using `sudo`

E.g:

`sudo cp conf/*.xml input`

Comment: I am using cygwin on Windows. And what about the JAVA_HOME not set?

Comment: I'm not sure about the JAVA_HOME. As far as Permission Denied, can you give the output of ls -la (so I can see permissions)? Maybe copy the output to Pastebin.com and just give me the link so you don't have to paste it into a comment.

Comment: conf
d---------+ 1 Harsh          None           0 Sep 26 20:30 contrib
----------+ 1 Harsh          None        6842 Jul 23 03:56 hadoop-ant-1.2.1.jar
----------+ 1 Harsh          None         414 Jul 23 03:56 hadoop-client-1.2.1.jar
----------+ 1 Harsh          None     4203147 Jul 23 03:56 hadoop-core-1.2.1.jar
----------+ 1 Harsh          None      142726 Jul 23 03:56 hadoop-

Comment: examples-1.2.1.jar
----------+ 1 Harsh          None         417 Jul 23 03:56 hadoop-minicluster-1.2.1.jar
----------+ 1 Harsh          None     3126576 Jul 23 03:56 hadoop-test-1.2.1.jar
----------+ 1 Harsh          None      385634 Jul 23 03:56 hadoop-tools-1.2.1.jar
drwxr-xr-x+ 1 Harsh          None           0 Sep 26 20:45 input

Comment: I have set the permissions. Its working. Only JAVA_HOME is left now.

Comment: What's the line you're using in env.sh to set JAVA_HOME?

Comment: export JAVA_HOME= "C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_26"

Comment: I'm not super familiar with Hadoop, but looking at http://www.cs.brandeis.edu/~rshaull/cs147a-fall-2008/hadoop-windows/, you may not need the "export" keyword. If that's not it, I'm not sure what else it would be.